# Why doesn't Perl's strict warn about an undeclared $a?

Tags: perl, strictures

Can someone please explain to me the below code. This behavior has been like this for a while (tested on 5.8.5, 5.8.8, 5.10.1, 5.12.2) so there must be a reason behind it?

```
$ perl -M5.012 -E '$aa=2'
Global symbol "$aa" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.

$ perl -M5.012 -E '$a=2'
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks rafl and brian d foy, I should've re-checked perldoc strict first.

Comment: Feel free to accept one of the answers, even if you have to roll dice. It will make that 44% below your name a little larger. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is in the [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) documentation:

> Because of their special use by sort(), the variables $a and $b
>   are exempted from this check.

Always check [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/). Most of the answers are in there :)

Answer (score 11):

`$a` (and also `$b`, and many others) is a global variable. It's intended to be used in the `sort` function, e.g. `sort { $a <=> $b } @list`. `perldoc perlvar` lists all of perl's built-in globals and their meaning.

Comment: Actually, I believe $a and $b are 'package globals' rather than full on global globals (if that makes any sense).  See [perldoc sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) where it says "...the elements to be compared are passed into the subroutine as the package global variables $a and $b...".

Comment: Yes, they are globals that aren't forced into the main:: namespace like some other globals as, for example, `$_`.